# How can I see my status on the fulfillment of my commitment?

Tags: discussion, support

When I first committed to the Tor proposal, it made me agree to be active on the site in the early days to ensure a successful beta. The agreement/commitment involved asking and answering some set of questions. This is sort of documented on the [Area 51 FAQ page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

My problem is that I don't remember how many questions and answers I agreed to contributing. And I can't find the specifics about what the commitment entailed anywhere. Is there any place I can see a clear view of my progress towards fulfilling this commitment?

Comment: Thanks for the willingness to follow through; I'm sure that everyone who wants this beta to be a success will agree that this is all too rare!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see your commitment progress anywhere.

A commitment is officially said to be 10 posts on the main site (not meta) all of which should have non-negative scores.

However, my commitment has been fulfilled to the site, even though I have just 7 posts, so I am not exactly sure what the limit is now. It may also be linked to the [beta badge](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta), since I received a commitment fulfilled notification at around the same time I earned the badge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not commit to contribute with a set number of questions and answers, but that you commit to helping with the site in some way, shape, or form. Think of it as a way of saying "Yes, I will definitely use this site and help it succeed".

Comment: That factor is there, but since commitment fulfillment notifications are auto-generated by the system, there has to be some fixed metric that is being used. This used to be number of posts, but it seems to have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

The SE suggested level of commitment is to at least 10 questions or answers

`I commit to participate actively in 'name' for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.` - any commitment page

Comment: Please add a link to the page where this quote is from?

Comment: This is definitely what I was referring to. Tor is the first Area 51 proposal I have committed to though, so I didn't know this is standard across all sites. Also, a link to this quote would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: @Runa: This text appears only when you commit. It is not in the documentation and the rulers of Stack Exchange say that it is so for the purpose so the commit is not taken literally - "I have done my 10 posts so that's it." They believe that such an uncertain commitment would last longer.

Comment: I noticed that few (1-2) days after end of private beta all user which made around 10 posts had the commitment fulfilled on Area 51.